Creating a single, large mosaic file in S3 from tiles that cannot fit into memory?
I'm trying to form a (very) large mosaic raster from constituent files in S3, and the amount of data is extremely large; I'm not sure on the actual size, but let's say it's really huge, say over a TB. However, I'm running into an issue which I do not see a way around.
So I have a number of raster tiles stored, and I can parallelize the reading of these tiles on a cluster of machines. I can also parallelize writing pieces of a large file to S3 (using MultipartUpload).
My issue is that the individual tile data is that of an entire file, not part of a file, and thus I don't think this approach will work. I'd imagine there is plenty of metadata within a raster file, and thus sticking the binary data together, I would think, would not create a coherent file at the end. Plus, how would the tile data "know" where to go in order to appear in the right location, relative to the other tiles, in the resultant file?
Is there a robust way of doing this already in Python, or at least an approach I could create myself to do it? Or is this even possible? I know generally such a large raster would be kept as individual tiles, but I'm trying to see if this is possible in any case.

https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html https://gdal.org/api/python/utilities.html#osgeo.gdal.BuildVRT

@user2856 I'm familiar with VRT, but since the result is only a reference to underlying data, any processing would be left unfinished. The idea would be to have a processed raster (projection change, resolution change, etc.) that could be read from without needing to do that processing again.

So build the VRT (in memory if using python with /vsimem/infiles.vrt), gdalwarp (or gdal.Warp in python) that to another VRT with res. change then write out the warped VRT to a final cloud optimized geotiff with gdal_translate (gdal.Translate in python). Basically you are building a processing pipeline without writing any intermediate data.  Note final step is to translate from warped VRT rather than writing warp output directly as gdal warp doesn't handle output compression well, best to do that as a separate step.
